# How to restrict docker push to certain tags

Tags: docker, docker-ucp

Is there a way using UCP that we can limit certain users to push only to certain tags for example, deny push to abc/batch_scheduler:1.0.0 but let them push to abc/batch_scheduler:dev123 ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The restrictions would need to be handled by the registry server, which for Docker EE would be DTR. With DTR, the restrictions on push access to a repository are all or nothing per repository, not per tag. However, you can create multiple repositories, allow developers to upload to one repository, and have a promotion policy to copy images matching specific criteria to another repository. The user does not need access to push images to the second repository, only the user that created the promotion policy needs access, which could be an administrator.